HtmlUnitAndroid click does not do anything
I am using HtmlUnit Android to scrap data from a website, I am able to create the web client and connect it to the website, but after clicking a button I cannot obtain further elements. In the code, the 1st print is executed but 2nd isn't. This code was working fine 3 months ago, and today I got an error which I got rid of by simpling update the html unit library from     implementation("net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-android:2.67.0") to implementation("org.htmlunit:htmlunit3-android:3.7.0").
Web scrapping code:
        val webClient = WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)

        webClient.options.isCssEnabled = false

        var page: HtmlPage = webClient.getPage("https://timetables.qmul.ac.uk/default.aspx")

        val locationsBtn: HtmlAnchor = page.getHtmlElementById("LinkBtn_locations")

        println(locationsBtn)

        page = locationsBtn.click()
        println(page.webResponse.contentAsString)


If I do the following

bring up https://timetables.qmul.ac.uk/default.aspx in a browser
Open the networks tab (f12)
Click the "Rooms" link

I can see two calls to default.aspx. The first happens quickly then the second causes a page refresh. I think you'll need to wait until the second load (either wait for a javascript condition to be true or simple sleep) before scraping further
Here's the link you are clicking
<a id="LinkBtn_locations" class="LinkButton" href="javascript:__doPostBack('LinkBtn_locations','')">Rooms&nbsp;</a>

Notice how the __doPostBack(...) calls both theForm.onsubmit() and theForm.submit() which I think is causing two loads of default.aspx
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>

Edit
Perhaps you could try a java based sleep
   page = locationsBtn.click()
   Thread.sleep(5_000L);

   // get a fresh page instance after sleeping since the page loads twice after the click
   page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getCurrentWindow().getEnclosedPage();
   
   println(page.webResponse.contentAsString)


Added code to make the web client enable JS and wait for background JS for 10s, did not work, thank you though!!

I'm not sure I'd trust the background JS wait logic since there's two page loads going on.  Also the page instance will change between the click and the sleep. Have you tried a Thread.sleep(...) in the java layer? See my edit above which get s a fresh page instance after a sleep

I tried that and did not work, thanks though. I am running this on an Android app and keep getting this log  2024-06-05 10:51:16.912 15472-15511 correctnessListenerImpl com.david.qmul_room_timetable_app    W  Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'. Back when this was working fine I do not remember seeing this log

You might need to construct your own POST request which passes __EVENTTARGET, __EVENTARGUMENT and __VIEWSTATE paremeters to default.aspx. This would require looking up the hidden __VIEWSTATE field value from the homepage

Will have a look at the end of next week - please open an issue for HtmlUnit.
